# non-zero divisors in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am asked to show the following:

$ab$ is a non-zero divisor of $R$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are both non-zero divisors of $R$.

$\Rightarrow)$  Suppose $ab$ is a non-zero divisor of R.  Then neither a nor b equal zero, thus $ab \neq 0.$  Also

$\exists c \in R$, $c \neq 0$ such that $(ab)c \neq 0.$  If $a(bc) \neq 0,$ then $bc \neq 0.$  Since $c \neq 0,$ we conclude that $b$ is a

non-zero divisor.  Similarly, if $c(ab) \neq 0,$ then $(ca)b \neq 0.$  This implies that $ca \neq 0.$  Hence $a$ must

be a non-zero divisor.

$\Leftarrow )$  Suppose $a$ and $b$ are both non-zero divisors.  Then $\exists d,e\in R, d \neq 0$ and $e\neq 0$ such that $ad \neq 0$

and $be \neq 0.$

I'm stuck on the second portion of the proof.  Also, is the first half correct?  Any clues on what to do next would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you're confused about the definitions. An nonzero element $a \in R$ is not a (left) zero divisor iff $ac \neq 0$ for all nonzero $c \in R$. For example, in $\mathbb Z_6$, $2 \cdot 4 \neq 0$, but that doesn't mean $2$ isn't a zero divisor.

Comment: ok, thank you.  I'll re-work the first part with the correct definition.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry I should have stated that we are supposed to assume that the ring is not commutative

Comment: I think you have to specify whether it is left, right, or two-side zero divisors for noncommutative ring. If it is two-side zero divisors,it is easy to prove. If it is left or right zero divisor only, the conclusion may be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For the second portion, try a proof by contradiction:
For non-zero divisors $a, b \in R$, suppose $(ab)c=0$ for nonzero $c$, then by associativity $a(bc)=0$...

Comment: Could you elaborate a little ?

Comment: That $a(bc)=0$ is a contradiction – we assumed that $a$ is not a zero divisor. The element $(bc) \in R$ is nonzero because $b$ is not a zero divisor, so $a(bc)=0$ would indicate that $a$ is a zero divisor, which is impossible.